# Changing button text with popup text input kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

So, I'm new to kivy and can't get this code to work. I'm trying  to update a button text with a popup text input. The popup shows when the button is pressed, and when it's dismissed it should update the text on the button with whatever text was typed in it.

I've tried many variations of this code, but no one have worked. Either nothing happens or I get this error:

AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'

Here it is:

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

class MainWidget(GridLayout):
    pass

class PopText(Popup):

    def textChange(self):
        MyButton().change()

    def getText(self):
        text = self.display
        return text

class MyButton(AnchorLayout):
    def change(self):
        self.ids.equip_bt.text = PopText().getText()
        print(self.ids.my_bt.text)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainWidget()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

my.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0
#:import F kivy.factory.Factory

<PopText>:
    size_hint: .7, .3
    title: "Input Text"
    on_dismiss: self.textChange()
    display: pop_text.text

    TextInput:
        id: pop_text
        focus: True
        multiline: False
        on_text_validate: root.dismiss()

<MyButton>:
    anchor_y: "top"
    anchor_x: "right"

    Button:
        id: my_bt
        text: "Input Text"
        on_release: F.PopText().open()

<MainWidget>:
    cols: 1
    rows: 2

    MyButton:
    MyButton:
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a minimum example of what you are trying to achieve. The hard part is connection the button from the Popup to the Button which opened it. I am going through the app class to achieve that. I got to admit it is not a pretty solution.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class PopupBttn(Button):
    def openPopup(self):
        Pop = TextPopup().open(self.text)

class TextPopup(Popup):
    def open(self, text, **kwargs):
        super(TextPopup, self).open(**kwargs)
        self.ids.txtipt.text = text 

class MyApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

kv file:

```
BoxLayout:
    PopupBttn:
        id: bttn
        text: 'open Popup'
        on_press: self.openPopup()

<TextPopup>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        TextInput:
            id: txtipt
        Button:
            text: "OK"
            on_release: app.root.ids.bttn.text=root.ids.txtipt.text
            on_release: root.dismiss()
```

---

Here is an updated version to use multiple buttons. Unfortunately, you will need to set ids and name to the string of id per Button.

python file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class PopupBttn(Button):
    def openPopup(self):
        print(self.name)
        Pop = TextPopup().open(self.text, self.name)


class TextPopup(Popup):
    bttnid = StringProperty()
    text = StringProperty()
    def open(self, text, id, **kwargs):
        super(TextPopup, self).open(**kwargs)
        self.ids.txtipt.text = text
        self.bttnid = id

    def setText(self):
        App.get_running_app().root.ids[self.bttnid].text = self.text

class MyApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

kv file

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    PopupBttn:
        name: 'one'
        id: one
        text: 'I am the first Button'
    PopupBttn:
        name: 'two'
        id: two
    PopupBttn:
        name: 'three'
        id: three
    PopupBttn:
        name: 'four'
        id: four
        text: 'I am the fourth button'



<PopupBttn>:
    text: 'open Popup'
    on_press: self.openPopup()

<TextPopup>:
    text: txtipt.text
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        TextInput:
            id: txtipt
        Button:
            text: "OK"
            on_release: root.setText()
            on_release: root.dismiss()
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thanks a lot. I don't understand the usage of super yet but I'll look at it. Cheers

Comment: super refers to the class from which TextPopup inherits, aka Button. More or less uses the open method from Popup and then does sth more, setting the text.

Comment: Hmm, interesting! And what if I wanted to create more than one button with this same behavior? I can only think of changing their ids and creating separate popup classes, but this doesn't seem very smart or clean. Is there another way?

Comment: one way would be using a PopupBttn which generates unique ids for each instance in the init method. Maybe like ``self.id = str(id(self))``. I will have a look into it, but I am busy until Friday and will take a look then. Remind me if I foregt it.

Comment: I really appreciate your time, friend. I'll see what I can do in the meantime.

Comment: added a second example for multiple buttons. You will need to set an id per Button yourself. Didn't manage to automate that. Ask if you have questions about the implementation.

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you very much... Now it's working just as I intended! Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

In order to update both buttons, you need to assign unique id to each of them. Please refer to the example below for details.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class MainWidget(GridLayout):
    btn_top = ObjectProperty()
    btn_bottom = ObjectProperty()


class PopText(Popup):
    pass


class MyButton(AnchorLayout):
    my_btn = ObjectProperty()


class TestApp(App):
    title = "Changing button text with popup text input Kivy"

    def build(self):
        return MainWidget()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0
#:import F kivy.factory.Factory

<PopText>:
    size_hint: .7, .3
    title: "Input Text"

    TextInput:
        focus: True
        multiline: False
        on_text_validate:
            app.root.btn_top.my_btn.text = self.text
            app.root.btn_bottom.my_btn.text = self.text
            root.dismiss()

<MyButton>:
    my_btn: my_bt
    anchor_y: "top"
    anchor_x: "right"

    Button:
        id: my_bt
        text: "Input Text"
        on_release: F.PopText().open()

<MainWidget>:
    btn_top: btn_top
    btn_bottom: btn_bottom
    cols: 1
    rows: 2

    MyButton:
        id: btn_top
    MyButton:
        id: btn_bottom
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you @ikolim! But my doubt was how to create more buttons each one updating only its own text. I have to create a dozen of them, but it seams I didn't get exactly how ids work and I keep getting errors like the one I described above :/ But thanks for your answer, anyway...

Comment: To create a dozen of buttons, you would use a for loop to do that as shown in my example where I created 9 buttons https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45934429/bind-a-function-to-multiple-dynamically-created-buttons-in-kivy/45942518#45942518

Comment: I'm so confused haha. I still have loads to learn, that's just my second week using kivy. But thank you a lot for your examples, I will surely study on them.